# Value of k in k nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: classification, knn

I have 7 classes that needs to be classified and I have 10 features. Is there a optimal value for k that I need to use in this case or do I have to run the KNN for values of k between 1 and 10 (around 10) and determine the best value with the help of the algorithm itself?

Comment: Might want to look at [this article](http://www.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/Final_version_maier_5681[0].pdf)

Comment: oh no, unfortunately iam not that knowledgeable enough to read and understand that paper. could someone please help me out :( ?

Answer (score 17):

In addition to [the article](http://www.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/Final_version_maier_5681%5B0%5D.pdf) I posted in the comments there is [this one](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/a-detailed-introduction-to-k-nearest-neighbor-knn-algorithm/) as well that suggests:

> Choice of k is very critical – A small value of k means that noise will have a higher influence on the result. A large value make it computationally expensive and kinda defeats the basic philosophy behind KNN (that points that are near might have similar densities or classes ) .A simple approach to select k is set k = n^(1/2).

It's going to depend a lot on your individual cases, sometimes it is best to run through each possible value for k and decide for yourself.

Comment: could you please tell me whether n stands for number of classes ?

Comment: You're classifying based on the features, so n stands for number of features.

Comment: If I have 93 features than will 97 be  an apt choice or i should choose 93^1/2?

Comment: As stated, you should have take n^0.5 (where n=no of data instances, not features) as a starting value for k and change it accordingly.

Comment: What does it mean if the "optimal k" did not give us the best results?

Answer (score 12):

Important thing to note in k-NN algorithm is the that the number of **features** and the number of **classes** both **don't play a part in determining the value of k** in k-NN algorithm. k-NN algorithm is an ad-hoc classifier used to classify test data based on distance metric, i.e a test sample is classified as Class-1 if there are more number of Class-1 training samples closer to the test sample compared to other Classes training samples. For Eg: If value of k = 5 samples, then the 5 closest training samples are selected based on a distance metric and then a voting for most number of samples per class is done. So if 3 samples belong to Class-1 and 2 belong to Class-5, then that test sample is classified as Class-1. So the value of **k** indicates the number of training samples that are needed to classify the test sample.

Coming to your question, the value of **k** is non-parametric and a general rule of thumb in choosing the value of **k** is **k = sqrt(N)/2**, where **N** stands for the **number of samples in your training dataset**. Another tip that I suggest is to try and keep the value of k odd, so that there is no tie between choosing a class but that points to the fact that training data is highly correlated between classes and using a simple classification algorithm such as k-NN would result in poor classification performance.

Answer (score 4):

In KNN, finding the value of k is not easy. A small value of k means that noise will have a higher influence on the result and a large value make it computationally expensive.

Data scientists usually choose :

1. An odd number if the number of classes is 2
2. Another simple approach to select k is set k = sqrt(n).
   where n = number of data points in training data.

Comment: The computational expense of a large `k` is not normally the most important issue. Large `k` will over-smooth ignoring local structure.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this out as an approach to running through different k values and visualizing it to help your decision making. I have used this quite a number of times and it gave me the result I wanted:

```
error_rate = []

for i in range(1,50):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    error_rate.append(np.mean(pred != y_test))

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.plot(range(1,50),error_rate, marker='o', markersize=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no pre-defined statistical methods to find the most favourable value of K. Choosing a very small value of K leads to unstable decision boundaries.
Value of K can be selected as k = sqrt(n). where n = number of data points in training data
Odd number is preferred as K value.

Most of the time below approach is followed in industry.
Initialize a random K value and start computing.
Derive a plot between error rate and K denoting values in a defined range. Then choose the K value as having a minimum error rate.
Derive a plot between accuracy and K denoting values in a defined range. Then choose the K value as having a maximum accuracy.
Try to find a trade off value of K between error curve and accuracy curve.