# how to determine k value for the k nearest neighbours algorithm for a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, knn

If we have a matrix for 6 rows and 10 columns we have to determine the k value.If we assume default k value is 5 and if we have less columns than 5 with same number of rows 6 can we assume that number of columns=k value is it correct?i.e rows=6 cols=4 then k=col-1 => k=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this question, [value of k in k nearest neighbour algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568897/value-of-k-in-k-nearest-neighbour-algorithm)

Same as the previous one. Usually, the rule of thumb is squareroot of number of features

```
k=n^(1/2)
```

where n is the number of features. In your case square-root of 10 is approximately 3, so the answer should be 3.

Comment: I learned that N is not number of features, but amount of records in that formula. Explain?

Comment: @Zimano : If I understand you correctly, amount of records in the formula is the number samples. It can not be no. of samples because machine learning algorithms "should be" independent of the number of samples. If you mean the formula in the as in classLables~feature1+feature2 etc. then that means the number of features.

Comment: Thank you :) I understand now!

Answer (score 7):

*k=n^(1/2)*

Where n is number of instances and **not** features.  [reference 1](https://www3.nd.edu/~steve/computing_with_data/17_Refining_kNN/refining_knn.html) , [reference 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=hIOBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA580&lpg=PA580&dq=finding+best+k+for+knn+square+root&source=bl&ots=FySKAx26uX&sig=V3SF7Xww1-Icehzm91iWGOjopkY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYh9GFr_DMAhXOsh4KHT3HCXkQ6AEIUzAI#v=onepage&q=finding%20best%20k%20for%20knn%20square%20root&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

k=sqrt(n) has not optimal result with the various dataset. Some dataset, its result is quite awful. For example, one paper for 90's [paper link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f635/b420ce0167e98695b2913e71251ccfa43931.pdf) says the best result of k is between 5-10 bu sqrt(n) gives us a 17. Some other papers suggest interesting suggestions such as local k value or weighted k.
        İt's obvious choose k it's not an easy choice. That does not have an easy formula for these and depends on our dataset. Best way to choose optimal k  is calculate accuracy of which k is best for our dataset. Generally, if our dataset is getting bigger, optimal k value is also increasing.