# K value vs Accuracy in KNN

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to learn KNN by working on Breast cancer dataset provided by UCI repository. The Total size of dataset is 699 with 9 continuous variables and 1 class variable.

I tested my accuracy on cross-validation set. For K =21 & K =19. Accuracy is 95.7%.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=21)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred_val = neigh.predict(X_val)
print accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred_val)
```

But for K= 1, I am getting Accuracy = 97.85%
K = 3, Accuracy = 97.14

I read

> Choice of k is very critical – A small value of k means that noise will have a higher influence on the result. A large value make it computationally expensive and kinda defeats the basic philosophy behind KNN (that points that are near might have similar densities or classes ) .A simple approach to select k is set k = n^(1/2). [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569262/3763608)

Which value of K should I consider for my model. Can you guys elaborate the logic behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Accuracy alone is nt a sufficient criterion. You also have to consider Recall.

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust,
Thanks for the suggestion. Will calculate Precision- recall and will update the post.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (it is not about progamming), and should be moved to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Or rather more likely, it has probably already been asked on CV and you should do a search before posting a new question.

Comment: But to be brief: there is no "correct" answer, that is, in all but the most simple cases, you will not know ahead of time which values for K will give you better performance (of course, higher K will always degrade computational performance).

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga,
I studied about the topic but still its not clear. I think stackoverflow is about help programmers.

Comment: @RahulSaxena Yes, well, it is not a simple topic with neat answers. And yes, Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You question has nothing to do with programming, and is soley related to statistics/machine-learning. It is better suited for the Stack Exchange cite specific for those topics.